# change desktop configuration

Tags: desktop-environments

I want to change my desktop to look and work like ubuntu 10. There were icons across the ?title bar? at the top of the desktop where you could choose applications, system, files & folders. I just upgraded to ubuntu 14 and can't find the icon for making multiple desktops. I don't like the way the new desktop is organized. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to install `gnome-session-flashback` to get that:

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-session-flashback
```

At the login screen, select "GNOME FLashback".

See these links for more info:

- [How-to Geek](http://www.howtogeek.com/189912/how-to-install-the-gnome-classic-desktop-in-ubuntu-14.04/)
- [OMG! Ubuntu](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2014/04/ubuntu-14-04-classic-gnome-flashback-session)
- [Web Upd8](http://www.webupd8.org/2014/04/how-to-install-and-tweak-gnome.html)